# How do I get a full width-image while using vertical scrollspy in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a responsive webpage using Bootstrap, with a vertical scrollspy on the left, with parallax scrolling on the right.
[It should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/absVS.jpg)

Currently this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Rwitaban Goswami</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            position: relative;
        }
        ul.nav-pills{
            top:20px;
            position:fixed;
        }
        .parallax{
            min-height:300px;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }
        .parallaxsec{
            background-image: url("DP.jpg");
        }
        .jumbotron{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .parallax h1 {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            font-size: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 60px;
            line-height: 100px;
          }
      p{
        font-size: 20px;
      }

    </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="20">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <nav id="scrollspy" class="col-sm-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#item-1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="jumbotron parallax parallaxsec">
                <h1 class="display-3">Rwitaban Goswami</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But this creates a layout which has too much white space, and the image width is very less. How do I get a preferable layout, with the scrollspy having no space to the left, and a good amount of width for the image and text?

Answer (score 0):

remove the "container" attribute to the first DIV as this added too much padding for your taste.

so the above code looks like:

```
        <div>
          <div class="row no-gutters">
    <nav id="scrollspy" class="col-sm-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#item-1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="jumbotron parallax parallaxsec">
            <h1 class="display-3">Rwitaban Goswami</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```